# Cannot validate JSON result

Tags: php, android, json, wamp

I'm trying to read JSON values in an android app and for that, I made a json_get_data.php file which contains the following code. I'm using WAMP server to host my files.

```
<?php 
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'lunch_menu') or die("could not connect");
$query="select * from lunch_menu";
$result=mysqli_query($link,$query);

$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  array_push($response,array("id"=>$row[0],"day"=>$row[1],"soup"=>$row[2],"non_veg_main"=>$row[3],"non_veg_side"=>$row[4],"veg_main"=>$row[5],"veg_side"=>$row[6]));
}

echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response));

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

The URL for the result is http://192.168.1.100/json_get_data.php

However, when I try to validate it using JSONlint or other validator tools, it tells me the URL is invalid even though loading the URL in the browser outputs a JSON file correctly.

Comment: Check the API with POSTMAN tool. It will show you the correct result of your api. And if there is any problem then it will also show you.

Comment: I'm not sure.. I'm not getting any response from your URL.

Comment: Try it now, my wifi stopped working. I changed it to my new ip adress.

Comment: I tried checking my url with POSTMAN tool and got no errors. It returned what I wanted it to.

Comment: The URL specified contains a local and will not be reachable from the internet: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#Private_addresses

Answer (score 0):

The localhost refers to the device on which the code is running, in this case the emulator.

If you want to refer to the computer which is running the Android simulator, use the IP address 10.0.2.2 instead.

Comment: There isn't anything running on android at the moment(I should remove the android part) but I'm just trying to validate the response from a php file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see here headers with content type, before echo you should add something like:
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');

Also because your ip is local, JSONLint wont see it. If you know what is vagrant you can use vagrant share or upload this file to real webserver (you can get amazon free tier for it).

But if your goal just to test your output, you can use postman chrome extension or tools like that.